# Table of Contents without Boldface Using KOMA Script tocbasic

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocbasic

I would like to have the complete TOC without setting the top level in boldface. In the past I used `tocloft` but KOMA throws a warning and suggests to use `tocbasic`. Unfortunately, I didn't understand from the documentation how to implement it.

Do you have a starting point to get the parts underlined in the attached figure red in normalfont?
[image: figure]

Here is the MWE:

```
% Magic comments for TeXstudio
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
% !TeX program = lualatex

% define class: scrreprt, scrartcl
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% load packages
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I use KOMA Script v3.30 in TeXlive 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just one `\setkomafont` away.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{sectionentry}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks! And it is `chapterentry` when using `scrrprt` class.